# retrieve specific record from mongodb database with angular2 in a MEAN app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, angular, observable

I'm learning how to build a MEAN application with angular2.
I can retrieve a list of items (mountains) from Mongo database in this way:

```
this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/mountains'
.map(response => {
                const data = response.json().obj;
                let objs: any[] = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    let mountain = new Mountain(data[i].name, data[i].elevation, data[i].image, null);
                    objs.push(mountain);
                }
                return objs;
            })
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.json()));
```

Now I don't want to retrieve all the mountains from my `mountains` collection but only one.
I tried in several way but without success...
This is one of my attempts:

```
    getMountain(mountainName: string) {      
return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/mountains/{name:mountainName}')
    ....
    }
```

mountains collection structure looks like this:

```
name: string
elevation: number
```

Comment: I think you got something confused here. You are sending a request to express, not to your mongodb. If you just want to receive a certain mountain, you have to make a route in express with an URL parameter for the name.

Comment: Maybe go through some tutorial as a starting point. Like this one here: http://www.davidniciforovic.com/2016/02/03/building-a-single-page-todo-app-with-mean-including-angular-2/